# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 for MS Access 2003

Tags: c#, database-connection, connection-string, ms-access-2003

I'll be specific here... my database is designed in Access 2007 with an `.accdb` extension.... I deployed my application where Office 2003 is installed.. I know the simple thing would be to just install Office 2007 on the machine. But is there any other way that can be done with??? I mean manipulating connection parameters like???

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..\\DBControl.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password";
```

This is my connection parameter....... if I use 4.0 version, will Excel 8.0 will it still be able to read the `.accdb` files? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I would store the available connection strings in a table, along with a Yes/No field called "Active".  Then, when the app is launched you can determine which version of Office is installed, set the Active field for that record to "Yes", and have your database pull the connection string out of the table based on which record is active.  Easily done with a DLookup command.  Bada-Bing!  Going forward, you just need to distribute a new version of the table with any additional connection strings you may need.  This way, you don't have to keep re-writing or re-editing the code.  Making everything table-driven has saved me WEEKS of coding time on projects I've worked on...